# MongoDB time range search

Tags: mongodb

Given a set of documents that contains an array of time start and end times:

```
{
   times: [
      { startAt: ... endAt: ...},
      { startAt: ... endAt: ...},
      { startAt: ... endAt: ...}
      ...
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to find all the documents which not only fall within a date range, but also a time of day.

For example, it is possible to query for all documents where at least one of the ranges ends on **any day** before the 1/1/16 where the end time for that day is >= 17:00?

Comment: You can make use $hour in aggregration framework to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best i can do is get the id of all documents where at least one of the ranges ends on any day before the 1/1/16 where the end time for that day is >= 17:00. You will have to query for the actual document again using the id to get full data

Sample data

```
db.times.insert({ time: [
    { startAt: new Date("2015-01-01 10:00"), endAt: new Date("2015-01-01 18:00") },
    { startAt: new Date("2015-01-02 10:00"), endAt: new Date("2015-01-02 18:00") } ]
});

db.times.insert({ time: [
    { startAt: new Date("2015-01-01 10:00"), endAt: new Date("2016-01-01 16:00") },
    { startAt: new Date("2015-01-02 10:00"), endAt: new Date("2015-01-02 16:00") } ]
});

db.times.insert({ time: [
    { startAt: new Date("2015-01-01 10:00"), endAt: new Date("2016-01-01 16:00") },
    { startAt: new Date("2015-01-02 10:00"), endAt: new Date("2016-01-02 16:00") } ]
});
```

To query

```
db.times.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$time" },
    { $project: { endHour: { $hour: "$time.endAt" }, time: { startAt: "$time.startAt", endAt: "$time.endAt" } } },
    { $match: { $and: [ { "time.endAt": { $lt: new Date("2016-01-01") } }, { endHour: { $gte: 9 }} ] } },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", time: { $push: { startAt: "$time.startAt", endAt: "$time.endAt" } } } }
]);
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2") }
```

Because the data we are looking for is in the array times, for project to work we will need to `unwind` it to be able to examine the endAt.
After first `unwind` stage the output is (also input for next stage)

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T11:00:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T09:00:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2016-01-01T09:00:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T09:00:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2016-01-01T09:00:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2016-01-02T09:00:00Z") } }
```

Then go to next stage the `$project`, we extract the hours from endAt and keep time object otherwise we will lost list

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T11:00:00Z") }, "endHour" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d2"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T09:00:00Z") }, "endHour" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2016-01-01T09:00:00Z") }, "endHour" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d3"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T09:00:00Z") }, "endHour" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-01T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2016-01-01T09:00:00Z") }, "endHour" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56659a492b9eaad2d9e6d4d4"), "time" : { "startAt" : ISODate("2015-01-02T03:00:00Z"), "endAt" : ISODate("2016-01-02T09:00:00Z") }, "endHour" : 9 }
```

Note that mongodb use ISODate, at my local time is GMT+7 so, the hourEnd is not 18 but 18-7=11
After this stage we already have all information we need, we can now filter based on endAt and endHour

`{ $match: { $and: [ { "time.endAt": { $lt: new Date("2016-01-01") } }, { endHour: { $gte: 10 }} ] } }`

In this `$match`, we want only document that endAt before 2016-01-01 and endHour greater than 10 (aka 17:00)

The last stage is only to group by id to remove redundant document

Hope that helps